How to make Swagger provide an upload operation for an interface?
Using ASP.NET Web API 2 requires an interface to read the file stream, how to make Swagger aware of it.
I'm using the .NET Framework 4.8.0.
This is my main code, I'm reading the file stream from Request.Content. I know ASP.NET Core can use IFormFile to make Swagger sense that a file upload is needed.
But ASP.NET Web API 2 doesn't have this interface class.
[HttpPost]
[Route("Import")]
[SwaggerOperation("UploadFile")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ImportCustomer()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

    if (fileBytes == null || fileBytes.Length == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("No file data found in request");
    }

    string fileName = GetFileNameFromContentDisposition(Request);
    string basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);

    using (var fileStream = File.Create(filePath))
    {
        await fileStream.WriteAsync(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    }

    return Ok("File uploaded successfully");
}

